# Reset admin password for Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm locked out of the admin page for our Kibana instance. I have a root shell on the box and can access all configurations. How do I go about resetting the admin password, so I can login to Kibana as admin? I can authenticate as kibana user, but I get this message when I try to manager users, "You do not have permission to manage users"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPack Security provides a [file realm](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/file-realm.html) whose purpose is to help you when you are locked out of the system.

First, add this to your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file:

```
xpack:
  security:
    authc:
      realms:
        file1:
          type: file
          order: 0
```

Then you can use the [`bin/x-pack/users`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/users-command.html) command to add a new user with

```
bin/x-pack/users useradd superguy
```

Then you can give that new user `superadmin` priviledges

```
bin/x-pack/users roles superguy -a superuser
```

Now you have a new user called `superguy` which has `superuser` role and you can use it to reset your admin password.